# iterative parameter inside a function - Python

Tags: python, function, filter, iteration, global

I'm building a function which receives 'chunks' of data and processes them iteratively.
My problem is how to save the last parameters for the next run, while still initializing it in the first run.

**Example:**

```
def IterativeFunction(X):      #X is the received vector (chunk of data)

    for i in range(len(X)):
        Y[i] = 0.1 * X[i] + 0.9 * Xn1
        Xn1 = X[i]                     #This is the iterative part

     return(Y)
```

The main function will receive 'Y' and then send the next 'chunk'.
So I need the IterativeFunction to run again with 'Xn' initialized to: "Xn1 = X[i] (of last run)".
I'll still need Xn1 to be initialized in the first run to "Xn1 = 0".

**Suggested solution:**
I can of course return "Xn1" and receive it again from the "main", but I'm sure there are better ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `Xn1` to the function and return `Xn1` together with `Y` every time the function is called. In the first time, it will be either be missing or `None` (or any other default value of your choice) and then you initialize it.

p.s note that `Y` is never initialized and so is `Xn1` in the original code.

Sketch -

```
def IterativeFunction(X, Xn1=None):
    if Xn1 is None:
       Xn1 = initialize
    for i in range(len(X)):
        Y[i] = 0.1 * X[i] + 0.9 * Xn1
        Xn1 = X[i]

     return(Y, Xn1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to keep track of how many times you've run the function, so the first run can run one piece of code, and the rest the other like this:

```
run_times = 0
def IterativeFunction(X):      #X is the received vector (chunk of data)
run_times += 1
if run_times == 1:
  for i in range(len(X)):
     Y[i] = 0.1 * X[i] + 0.9 * Xn1
     Xn1 = X[i]                     #This is the iterative part
else:
   blablah


 return(Y)
```

Not sure which way you want it to work but you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above answers. I combined your ideas into this:

```
def Main_function():

   #init
   Xn1 = 0
   
   #Code part
   ...code code code...

   call IterativeFunction( VectorX , Xn1)

   end 

def IterativeFunction( VectorX , Xn1):
   
   for i in range(len(X)):
      Y[i] = 0.1 * X[i] + 0.9 * Xn1
      Xn1 = X[i]                    
   return (Y , Xn1)
```

My question is about other ways to achieve this, like global parameter? or is this the most recommended way to achieve a solution?

Comment: Global parameters are generally agreed to be code smells, unless you're writing a quick n' dirty script. Btw, if the other answers helped you, it's considered good etiquette to upvote them, even if you don't want to accept any particular one.